# Need to generate CREATE TABLE scripts and INSERT scripts in order

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    a_id  NUMBER(10),
    city  VARCHAR2(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_a PRIMARY KEY ( a_id )
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    b_id  NUMBER(10),
    a_id  NUMBER(10),
    city  VARCHAR2(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_b PRIMARY KEY ( b_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_b_a FOREIGN KEY ( a_id )
        REFERENCES a ( a_id )
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES(1,'Mumbai');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(2,'Pune');
INSERT INTO b VALUES(1,1,'Mumbai');
INSERT INTO b VALUES(2,2,'Pune');

COMMIT;
```

I need to generate a `create table` ddl scripts in order of parent-child. Suppose, I have two tables `A` and `B` then script should give me ddl for table `A` and then for `B`.

From the below query I can get the parent child tables but how to generate ddl out of it.

```
SELECT p.table_name PARENT_TABLE, c.table_name CHILD_TABLE
FROM dba_constraints p, dba_constraints c
WHERE (p.constraint_type = 'P' OR p.constraint_type = 'U')
AND c.constraint_type = 'R'
AND p.constraint_name = c.r_constraint_name
AND p.table_name = UPPER('A')
and p.owner='TAM';
```

And same for `INSERT` DML scripts. I need to have the DML scripts in the order of parent-child.
I am stuck in generating the scripts.

Comment: Use a third-party tools like redgate.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie In oracle we have ```metadata.get_ddl``` function. So, can't we use some query to do this

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4495882/need-to-generate-create-table-scripts-and-insert-scripts-in-order#latest

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother.

I presume your intention is to *port* current schema to another schema/database.

- if you already have such a script - that creates tables in   appropriate order, as well as inserts rows into them - reuse it

  - you could help yourself if you first created tables (without foreign key constraints), then inserted rows, then created foreign key constraints (using `alter table add constraint ...`)
- however, I'd suggest you to use **Data Pump** instead (or maybe even the *original* `EXP` and `IMP` utilities) - export will *export* the whole schema (if that's what you're doing) into a .DMP file; import would then import it into another schema, taking care about foreign key constraints (basically, it would do as I wrote before - apply constraints at the end of import)

  - it means that you don't have to take care about *what comes first* - Oracle will do everything for you